# how to change dcm4chee ui

Tags: java, maven, ant, dcm4che

I am a new java developer, I'm trying to run dcm4chee project and after handling a lot of trouble, finally I successfully ran it.
now i want to change dcm4chee UI, but any change in the source will not end up output changes.
commands that I use to run are:

```
d:
cd D:\source\cleanversion\dcm4jboss-all\dcm4jboss-build
del /F target\dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql.zip
ant mysql-dist
rd /s /q c:\apps\dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql
unzip.exe -o -qq D:\source\cleanversion\dcm4jboss-all\dcm4jboss-build\target\dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql.zip -d c:\apps\
c:
cd C:\apps\dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql\bin
install_jboss.bat c:\apps\jboss-4.2.3.GA
cd C:\apps\dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql\sql
mysql -uroot -proot
drop database pacsdb;
create database pacsdb;
drop database arrdb;
create database pacsdb;

grant all on pacsdb.* to 'pacs'@'localhost' identified by 'pacs';
grant all on arrdb.* to 'arr'@'localhost' identified by 'arr';
\q
mysql -upacs -ppacs pacsdb < create.mysql

c:
cd C:\apps\dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql\bin
install_arr.bat C:\apps\dcm4chee-arr-3.0.11-mysql

c:
cd C:\apps\dcm4chee-web-3.0.2-mysql\bin
install.bat C:\apps\dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql

call C:\apps\dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql\bin\run.bat
```

my source code contains these folders:

```
-dcm4che14

-dcm4chee-arr

-dcm4chee-audit

-dcm4chee-docstore

-dcm4chee-xds-infoset

-dcm4chee-arc3-entities

-dcm4chee-icons

-dcm4chee-web-common

-dcm4chee-dashboard

-dcm4chee-usr

-dcm4chee-cleanup

-dcm4chee-web

-dcm4jboss-all
```

for example when I change "login.jsp","base-style.css" and some gif (logo.fig) from dcm4chee-web-common folder,
then I build the project with "ant mysql-dist" command, and create "dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql.zip" and follow the install instruction mentioned in http://www.marcilan.com/2012/11/installing-dcm4chee-2-7-2-with-mysql-and-weasis-web-viewer-under-windows-7/ but changes are not applied.

so I decided to download "dcm4chee-web-3.0.2-scr.zip" insted of "dcm4chee-web-3.0.2-mysql.zip" and try to manually build the dcm4chee-web source.

I use this command for that purpose:

```
cd D:\source\cleanversion\dcm4chee-web\dcm4chee-web-dist
mvn -Ddb=mysql assembly:assembly
```

and I got this error:

```
D:\source\cleanversion\dcm4chee-web\dcm4chee-web-dist>mvn -Ddb=mydsql assembly:a
ssembly
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
dcm4che.dcm4chee:dcm4chee-web-dist:pom:3.0.2
[WARNING] The expression ${version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.version}
 instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.version}
 instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.version}
 instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Assemble Distribution for WEB3 3.0.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) > package @ d
cm4chee-web-dist >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) < package @ d
cm4chee-web-dist <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) @ dcm4chee-we
b-dist ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/bin.xml
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
web-ear/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-ear-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-web-ear/
3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-ear-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
web-ear/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-ear-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
web-urlprovider/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-urlprovider-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-web-urlp
rovider/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-urlprovider-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
web-urlprovider/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-urlprovider-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
web-licenseprovider/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-licenseprovider-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-web-lice
nseprovider/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-licenseprovider-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
web-licenseprovider/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-licenseprovider-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
dashboard-sar-auditlog/3.0.2/dcm4chee-dashboard-sar-auditlog-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-dashboar
d-sar-auditlog/3.0.2/dcm4chee-dashboard-sar-auditlog-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
dashboard-sar-auditlog/3.0.2/dcm4chee-dashboard-sar-auditlog-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
web-sar-auditlog/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-sar-auditlog-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-web-sar-
auditlog/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-sar-auditlog-3.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-
web-sar-auditlog/3.0.2/dcm4chee-web-sar-auditlog-3.0.2.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.588 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-07T18:57:53+04:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.
2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) on project dcm4chee-web-dist: Failed to create a
ssembly: Failed to resolve dependencies for project: dcm4che.dcm4chee:dcm4chee-w
eb-dist:pom:3.0.2: Unable to get dependency information for dcm4che.dcm4chee:dcm
4chee-web-ear:ear:mydsql:3.0.2: Failed to retrieve POM for dcm4che.dcm4chee:dcm4
chee-web-ear:ear:mydsql:3.0.2: Failure to transfer dcm4che.dcm4chee:dcm4chee-web
-ear:pom:3.0.2 from http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org was cached in the l
ocal repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
 codehaus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not
 transfer artifact dcm4che.dcm4chee:dcm4chee-web-ear:pom:3.0.2 from/to codehaus-
snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): Failed to transfer file: h
ttp://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/dcm4che/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-web-ear/3.0.2/
dcm4chee-web-ear-3.0.2.pom. Return code is: 410 , ReasonPhrase:Gone.
[ERROR] dcm4che.dcm4chee:dcm4chee-web-ear:ear:3.0.2
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] codehaus-snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org, releases=t
rue, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] wicketstuff (http://wicketstuff.org/maven/repository, releases=true, sna
pshots=true),
[ERROR] dcm4che (http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2, releas
es=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] glassfish-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/glassf
ish, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public, releases
=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] Maven Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=f
alse),
[ERROR] ejb3unit (http://ejb3unit.sourceforge.net/maven2, releases=true, snapsho
ts=false),
[ERROR] central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=f
alse)
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) dcm4che.dcm4chee:dcm4chee-web-dist:pom:3.0.2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
D:\source\cleanversion\dcm4chee-web\dcm4chee-web-dist>
```

is this the right way to change UI?

Comment: i check the website and i found the last version is 18.0.1 but you use dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql . where did you get this version?

Comment: I create that with "ant mysql-dist" from source